# Вхождения точек в полигон WMS CQL_FILTER CONTAINS

Tags: geoserver

есть 10000 точек разбросанных по стране. Точки в PostGIS. Тип данных - geometry. Отрисовываю их на карте с помощью WMS. Пользователь рисует на карте произвольный полигон. И нужно, чтобы остались только те точки, которые попали в полигон. CQL_FILTER поддерживает пространственную функцию CONTAINS. Только не понятно, что именно передавать ей в качестве параметра: столбец с пространственными данными (точки), столбец в формате WKT, по одной точке? Помогите разобраться!

```
CONTAINS(geom,POLYGON((50.470625922905825 69.94117797851558,48.49543286206654 78.11500610351563,46.953690400110204 76.84059204101563,46.863341406105214 71.39137329101561,50.470625922905825 69.94117797851558)))
```

geom - столбец в PostGIS с пространственными данными, POLYGON - полигон, нарисованный пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

INTERSECTS(geom,POLYGON((50.470625922905825 69.94117797851558,48.49543286206654 78.11500610351563,46.953690400110204 76.84059204101563,46.863341406105214 71.39137329101561,50.470625922905825 69.94117797851558)))